# Form in display absolute doesn't appear completely when Shrinking screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using also bootstrap columns and have a form that is in `display: absolute`. I have a problem when i shrink the screen the form doesn't appear completely as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFPSq.png).

How to make it appear completely? the result i'm looking to achieve : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G30g4.png).

The html code & css from the class `form`:

```css
.form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:80px;
    width:540px;
    height:650px;
    background:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 left">
            <div class="wrapper">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 px-0">
            <div class="imageWrapper">
                <img class="homePhoto" src="images/photo-home">
                <img class="formShape" src="images/forme_blue_half.png">
                <div class="form" id="form">
                    <h2>LET'S TALK</h2>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <input class="input field" type="text" id="name" name="user_name" placeholder="LAST NAME&#42;" required>
                        <br/>
                        <input class="input field" type="text" id="firstName" name="user_firstName" placeholder="FIRST NAME&#42;" required>
                        <br/>
                        <input class="input field" type="email" id="email" name="user_mail" placeholder="E-MAIL&#42;" required>
                        <br/>
                        <input class="input field" type="text" id="organization" name="user_organizationName" placeholder="ORGANIZATION NAME">
                        <br/>
                        <textarea class="field fieldTextArea" id="msg" name="user_message" placeholder="PLEASE TELL US ABOUT YOUR NEEDS&#42;" required></textarea>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="checkboxContainer">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="receiveEmails" name="receiveEmails" checked disabled>
                            <label class="checkbox" for="receiveEmails">I would like to receive information e-mails</label>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <input class="button submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your main goal of your css class .form? It is the one causing for your form to not show properly.

Comment: @tontonsevilla the class .form i use it to show the form in absolute position and place it at the center of the column. If you can see the picture i added to the question you will see that the form content isn't appearing completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the width and the code that you have with px and change that to 100%.

```
    .form {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        display:block;
        margin-bottom:80px;
        width:100%;
        height:650px;
        background:#fff;
        border-radius:5px;
        overflow:hidden;
        z-index:1;
    }
```